# table tr create based on order item count

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order

I create table tr based on order but if order have 3 product it create 3 tr how to avoid this

```
$ordershippeddays = 7; // number of days you want
    $fromDate = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", gmmktime(0, 0, 0, gmdate("m"), gmdate("d") - $ordershippeddays, gmdate("Y")));
    $toDate = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", gmmktime(23, 59, 59, gmdate("m"), gmdate("d"), gmdate("Y")));

    $formatFromDate = gmdate("M-d-Y", gmmktime(0, 0, 0, gmdate("m"), gmdate("d") - $ordershippeddays, gmdate("Y")));
    $formatToDate = gmdate("M-d-Y", gmmktime(23, 59, 59, gmdate("m"), gmdate("d"), gmdate("Y")));
     $ordercollection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('order_id')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from' => $fromDate, 'to' => $toDate))->setPageSize(10000);
      $orderCount = count($ordercollection);

    $processedTemplate="";
    $tableHeaderHtml = '<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="650" style="border:1px solid #eaeaea"><thead><tr>';
    $tableHeaderHtml .= '<th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px;padding:3px 9px;border-right:1px dotted #cccccc;">Order Id</th><th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px;padding:3px 9px;border-right:1px dotted #cccccc;">Name</th>';
    $tableHeaderHtml .= '<th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px;padding:3px 9px;border-right:1px dotted #cccccc;">Email</th><th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px;padding:3px 9px;border-right:1px dotted #cccccc;">Source</th><th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px;padding:3px 9px;border-right:1px dotted #cccccc;">Payment Method</th>';
    $tableHeaderHtml .= '<th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px;padding:3px 9px;border-right:1px dotted #cccccc;">Order Status</th><th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px;padding:3px 9px;border-right:1px dotted #cccccc;">Total</th><th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px;padding:3px 9px;border-right:1px dotted #cccccc;">Order Date</th><th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px;padding:3px 9px;border-right:1px dotted #cccccc;">Product Name</th>';
    $tableHeaderHtml .= '<th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px;padding:3px 9px;border-right:1px dotted #cccccc;">Billing Address</th><th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px;padding:3px 9px;border-right:1px dotted #cccccc;">Shipping Address</th>';
    $tableHeaderHtml .= '</tr></thead><tbody bgcolor="#F6F6F6">';
    $arraything=[];
    $currency = Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())->getSymbol();
    foreach ($ordercollection as  $ordervalue) {
      $eid = $ordervalue->getOrderId(); 
      $order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->load($eid);
      $orderCreated = date("M-d-Y", Mage::getModel("core/date")->timestamp($order->getCreatedAt()));
      $customerStatus = $order->getCustomerId();
      if($customerStatus == Null){
          $isCustomer = 'Guest';
      }else{
          $isCustomer = 'Customer';
      }
      $placedFrom = $order->getRemoteIp();
      if($placedFrom > 0 ){
          $placedSource = $placedFrom;
      }
      else{
          $placedSource = "Mobile";
      }
      /*Mage::log("Testing success...........");*/
      $orderInfo = $order->getIncrementId().',,'.$order->getStatusLabel().','.number_format ($order->getGrandTotal(), 2, '.' , $thousands_sep = '');
      $userDetails = $order->getCustomerName().','.$order->getCustomerEmail();            
      $billingAddress = $order->getBillingAddress();
      $shipping_address = $order->getShippingAddress();
      $billingAddressFull = $billingAddress->getStreetFull().','.$billingAddress->getRegion().','.$billingAddress->getPostcode().','.$billingAddress->getCountry().', Mob: '.$billingAddress->getTelephone();
      $shipping_addressFull = $shipping_address->getStreetFull().','.$shipping_address->getRegion().','.$shipping_address->getPostcode().','.$shipping_address->getCountry().', Mob: '.$shipping_address->getTelephone();
        $tableContentHtml = '<tr>';
        $tableContentHtml .= '<td align="center" valign="middle" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;border-right:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $order->getIncrementId() . '</td><td align="center" valign="middle" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;border-right:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $order->getCustomerName() .'<br/><b>'.($isCustomer). '</b></td>';
        $tableContentHtml .= '<td align="center" valign="middle" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;border-right:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $order->getCustomerEmail() . '</td><td align="center" valign="middle" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;border-right:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $placedSource . '</td><td align="center" valign="middle" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;border-right:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getTitle() . '</td>';
        $tableContentHtml .= '<td align="center" valign="middle" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;border-right:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $order->getStatusLabel() . '</td><td align="center" valign="middle" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;border-right:1px dotted #cccccc;">' .$currency . number_format ($order->getGrandTotal(), 2, '.' , $thousands_sep = '') . '</td><td align="center" valign="middle" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;border-right:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $orderCreated . '</td><td align="center" valign="middle" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;border-right:1px dotted #cccccc;">';
        foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
             $productDetails = $item->getName().','.$item->getSku().', Qty: '.(int)$item->getQtyOrdered();
            $productName = $item->getName();
         $tableContentHtml .= $productName . '<br />';
       }
        $tableContentHtml .='</td>';
        $tableContentHtml .= '<td align="center" valign="middle" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;border-right:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $billingAddressFull . '</td><td align="center" valign="middle" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;border-right:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $shipping_addressFull . '</td>';
        $tableContentHtml .= '</tr>'; 
        $arraything[]=$tableContentHtml;
        }
        if($orderCount > 0){
          $template_id = 'order_update_email';
            $email_template  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault($template_id);
            $store = Mage::app()->getStore();
                  $iDefaultStoreId = Mage::app()
                  ->getWebsite()
                  ->getDefaultGroup()
                  ->getDefaultStoreId();
                  $email_template->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $iDefaultStoreId));
            $email_template_variables = array(
                'custom_variable' => $formatFromDate,
                'custom_variable1' => $formatToDate,
                'custom_variable3' =>$orderCount,
                'custom_variable4'=>$orderInfo,
                'custom_variable5'=>$tableHeaderHtml,
                'custom_variable6'=>implode(' ', $arraything)

            );
          $processedTemplate = $email_template->getProcessedTemplate($email_template_variables); 
      }else{
        $template_id_for_no_order = 'no_order_report';
            $email_template  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault($template_id_for_no_order);
            $store = Mage::app()->getStore();
                  $iDefaultStoreId = Mage::app()
                  ->getWebsite()
                  ->getDefaultGroup()
                  ->getDefaultStoreId();
                  $email_template->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $iDefaultStoreId));
            $email_template_variables = array(
                'custom_variable' => $formatFromDate,
                'custom_variable1' => $formatToDate

            );
          $processedTemplate = $email_template->getProcessedTemplate($email_template_variables); 
      }
      echo $processedTemplate;
```

Comment: please provide sample template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **group** `$ordercollection->getSelect()->group('order_id');`

```
 $ordershippeddays = 4257; // number of days you want
        $fromDate = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", gmmktime(0, 0, 0, gmdate("m"), gmdate("d") - $ordershippeddays, gmdate("Y")));
        $toDate = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", gmmktime(23, 59, 59, gmdate("m"), gmdate("d"), gmdate("Y")));

         $ordercollection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('order_id')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from' => $fromDate, 'to' => $toDate));
        $ordercollection->getSelect()->group('order_id'); $ordercollection->setPageSize(7);
    $processedTemplate="";
     $tableHeaderHtml = '<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="650" style="border:1px solid #eaeaea"><thead><tr>';
        $tableHeaderHtml .= '<th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px;padding:3px 9px;">Order Id</th><th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px;padding:3px 9px;">Name</th>';
        $tableHeaderHtml .= '<th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px;padding:3px 9px;">Email</th><th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px;padding:3px 9px;">Payment Method</th>';
        $tableHeaderHtml .= '<th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px;padding:3px 9px;">Order Status</th><th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px;padding:3px 9px;">Product Name</th>';
        $tableHeaderHtml .= '<th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px;padding:3px 9px;">Billing Address</th><th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px;padding:3px 9px;">Shipping Address</th>';
        $tableHeaderHtml .= '</tr></thead><tbody bgcolor="#F6F6F6">';
        $arraything=[];
    foreach ($ordercollection as  $ordervalue) {
                echo $eid = $ordervalue->getOrderId(); 
                $order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->load($eid);
                Mage::log("Testing success...........");
                $orderInfo = $order->getIncrementId().',,'.$order->getStatusLabel().','.number_format ($order->getGrandTotal(), 2, '.' , $thousands_sep = '');
                $userDetails = $order->getCustomerName().','.$order->getCustomerEmail();            
                $billingAddress = $order->getBillingAddress();
                $shipping_address = $order->getShippingAddress();
         //       Mage::log($billingAddressFull = $billingAddress->getStreetFull().','.$billingAddress->getRegion().','.$billingAddress->getPostcode().','.$billingAddress->getCountry().', Mob: '.$billingAddress->getTelephone());
           //     Mage::log($shipping_addressFull = $shipping_address->getStreetFull().','.$shipping_address->getRegion().','.$shipping_address->getPostcode().','.$shipping_address->getCountry().', Mob: '.$shipping_address->getTelephone());
            $tableContentHtml = '<tr>';
            $tableContentHtml .= '<td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $order->getIncrementId() . '</td><td align="center" valign="top" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $order->getCustomerName() . '</td>';
            $tableContentHtml .= '<td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $order->getCustomerEmail() . '</td><td align="center" valign="top" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getTitle() . '</td>';
            $tableContentHtml .= '<td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $order->getStatusLabel() . '</td><td align="center" valign="top" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;">';
            foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
                 $productDetails = $item->getName().','.$item->getSku().', Qty: '.(int)$item->getQtyOrdered();
                $productName = $item->getName();


             $tableContentHtml .= $productName . '<hr><br />';
           // Mage::log($productName,null,'custom.log');

             // $sender_name = 'Admin';
             // $sender_email = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email');
             // $email_template->setSenderName($sender_name);
             // $email_template->setSenderEmail($sender_email); 
            //  $email_template->send($email_to, $customer_name, $email_template_variables);


            }
            $tableContentHtml .='</td>';
            $tableContentHtml .= '<td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $billingAddressFull . '</td><td align="center" valign="top" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $shipping_addressFull . '</td>';
            $tableContentHtml .= '</tr>'; 
            $arraything[]=$tableContentHtml;

             // print_r($email_template_variables);



            }


    $template_id = 'order_update_email';
              $email_to = 'my@gmail.com';
              $customer_name   = "Test";
              $email_template  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault($template_id);
              $store = Mage::app()->getStore();
                    $iDefaultStoreId = Mage::app()
                    ->getWebsite()
                    ->getDefaultGroup()
                    ->getDefaultStoreId();
                    $email_template->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $iDefaultStoreId));
             // print_r($email_template);
              $custom_variable = "Nmae";
              $custom_variable1 = 'my@gmail.com';
              $custom_variable2 = '1234567890';
              $email_template_variables = array(
                  'custom_variable' => $fromDate,
                  'custom_variable1' => $toDate,
                  'custom_variable3' =>$orderCount,
                  'custom_variable4'=>$orderInfo,
                  'custom_variable5'=>$tableHeaderHtml,
                  'custom_variable6'=>implode(' ', $arraything)

              );
            $processedTemplate = $email_template->getProcessedTemplate($email_template_variables); 
            echo $processedTemplate;

            $mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
    $mail->setToName('Your Name');
    $mail->setToEmail('Youe Email');
    $mail->setBody($processedTemplate);
    $mail->setSubject('Mail Subject');
    $mail->setFromEmail('Sender Mail Id');
    $mail->setFromName("Msg to Show on Subject");
    $mail->setType('html');// YOu can use Html or text as Mail format
    $mail->send();
```

output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

html tag in your code not end propely. I have corrected as given below:

```
$formatFromDate = gmdate("M-d-Y", gmmktime(0, 0, 0, gmdate("m"), gmdate("d") - $ordershippeddays, gmdate("Y")));
$formatToDate = gmdate("M-d-Y", gmmktime(23, 59, 59, gmdate("m"), gmdate("d"), gmdate("Y")));
 $ordercollection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')
->addAttributeToSelect('order_id')
->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from' => $fromDate, 'to' => $toDate))->setPageSize(10000);
  $orderCount = count($ordercollection);

$processedTemplate="";
$tableHeaderHtml = '<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="650" style="border:1px solid #eaeaea"><thead><tr>';
$tableHeaderHtml .= '<th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px;padding:3px 9px;border-right:1px dotted #cccccc;">Order Id</th><th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px;padding:3px 9px;border-right:1px dotted #cccccc;">Name</th>';
$tableHeaderHtml .= '<th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px;padding:3px 9px;border-right:1px dotted #cccccc;">Email</th><th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px;padding:3px 9px;border-right:1px dotted #cccccc;">Source</th><th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px;padding:3px 9px;border-right:1px dotted #cccccc;">Payment Method</th>';
$tableHeaderHtml .= '<th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px;padding:3px 9px;border-right:1px dotted #cccccc;">Order Status</th><th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px;padding:3px 9px;border-right:1px dotted #cccccc;">Total</th><th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px;padding:3px 9px;border-right:1px dotted #cccccc;">Order Date</th><th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px;padding:3px 9px;border-right:1px dotted #cccccc;">Product Name</th>';
$tableHeaderHtml .= '<th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px;padding:3px 9px;border-right:1px dotted #cccccc;">Billing Address</th><th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px;padding:3px 9px;border-right:1px dotted #cccccc;">Shipping Address</th>';
$tableHeaderHtml .= '</tr></thead><tbody bgcolor="#F6F6F6">';
$arraything=[];
$currency = Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())->getSymbol();
foreach ($ordercollection as  $ordervalue) {
  $eid = $ordervalue->getOrderId(); 
  $order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->load($eid);
  $orderCreated = date("M-d-Y", Mage::getModel("core/date")->timestamp($order->getCreatedAt()));
  $customerStatus = $order->getCustomerId();
  if($customerStatus == Null){
      $isCustomer = 'Guest';
  }else{
      $isCustomer = 'Customer';
  }
  $placedFrom = $order->getRemoteIp();
  if($placedFrom > 0 ){
      $placedSource = $placedFrom;
  }
  else{
      $placedSource = "Mobile";
  }
  /*Mage::log("Testing success...........");*/
  $orderInfo = $order->getIncrementId().',,'.$order->getStatusLabel().','.number_format ($order->getGrandTotal(), 2, '.' , $thousands_sep = '');
  $userDetails = $order->getCustomerName().','.$order->getCustomerEmail();            
  $billingAddress = $order->getBillingAddress();
  $shipping_address = $order->getShippingAddress();
  $billingAddressFull = $billingAddress->getStreetFull().','.$billingAddress->getRegion().','.$billingAddress->getPostcode().','.$billingAddress->getCountry().', Mob: '.$billingAddress->getTelephone();
  $shipping_addressFull = $shipping_address->getStreetFull().','.$shipping_address->getRegion().','.$shipping_address->getPostcode().','.$shipping_address->getCountry().', Mob: '.$shipping_address->getTelephone();
    $tableContentHtml = '<tr>';
    $tableContentHtml .= '<td align="center" valign="middle" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;border-right:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $order->getIncrementId() . '</td><td align="center" valign="middle" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;border-right:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $order->getCustomerName() .'<br/><b>'.($isCustomer). '</b></td>';
    $tableContentHtml .= '<td align="center" valign="middle" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;border-right:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $order->getCustomerEmail() . '</td><td align="center" valign="middle" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;border-right:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $placedSource . '</td><td align="center" valign="middle" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;border-right:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getTitle() . '</td>';
    $tableContentHtml .= '<td align="center" valign="middle" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;border-right:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $order->getStatusLabel() . '</td><td align="center" valign="middle" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;border-right:1px dotted #cccccc;">' .$currency . number_format ($order->getGrandTotal(), 2, '.' , $thousands_sep = '') . '</td><td align="center" valign="middle" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;border-right:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $orderCreated . '</td><td align="center" valign="middle" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;border-right:1px dotted #cccccc;">';
    foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
         $productDetails = $item->getName().','.$item->getSku().', Qty: '.(int)$item->getQtyOrdered();
        $productName = $item->getName();
     $tableContentHtml .= $productName . '<br />';
   }
    $tableContentHtml .='</td>';
    $tableContentHtml .= '<td align="center" valign="middle" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;border-right:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $billingAddressFull . '</td><td align="center" valign="middle" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;border-right:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $shipping_addressFull . '</td>';
    $tableContentHtml .= '</tr>'; 
    $arraything[]=$tableContentHtml;
    }
$tableHeaderHtml .= '</tbody></table>'; 
    if($orderCount > 0){
      $template_id = 'order_update_email';
        $email_template  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault($template_id);
        $store = Mage::app()->getStore();
              $iDefaultStoreId = Mage::app()
              ->getWebsite()
              ->getDefaultGroup()
              ->getDefaultStoreId();
              $email_template->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $iDefaultStoreId));
        $email_template_variables = array(
            'custom_variable' => $formatFromDate,
            'custom_variable1' => $formatToDate,
            'custom_variable3' =>$orderCount,
            'custom_variable4'=>$orderInfo,
            'custom_variable5'=>$tableHeaderHtml,
            'custom_variable6'=>implode(' ', $arraything)

        );
      $processedTemplate = $email_template->getProcessedTemplate($email_template_variables); 
  }else{
    $template_id_for_no_order = 'no_order_report';
        $email_template  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault($template_id_for_no_order);
        $store = Mage::app()->getStore();
              $iDefaultStoreId = Mage::app()
              ->getWebsite()
              ->getDefaultGroup()
              ->getDefaultStoreId();
              $email_template->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $iDefaultStoreId));
        $email_template_variables = array(
            'custom_variable' => $formatFromDate,
            'custom_variable1' => $formatToDate

        );
      $processedTemplate = $email_template->getProcessedTemplate($email_template_variables); 
  }
  echo $processedTemplate;
```